# Android adding dynamic ImageViews to HorizontalScrollView does not work

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontalscrollview

I am desperately trying to achieve this for a quite long time but still could not make it work.
I have a ListView where in inside my Adapter I am trying to add image views dynamically based on my data. But, ScrollView does not show up with added images. When I tried myLinearLayout.getChildCount(), it gives proper results!!

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated :)

```
<!-- ScrollView (This lies inside listView's child view) -->
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_txn_horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view_linear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/header_bg">
       </LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>

LinearLayout sharedWithView = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_linear);
for (User sharer : data.getSharerModelList()) {
       ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) mInflator.inflate(R.layout.photo, null);
       Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext())
          .load(expense.getPayeeModel().getProfilePicUrl())
          .centerCrop()
          .resize(QuickReturnUtils.dp2px(mImageView.getContext(), 38),
                                    QuickReturnUtils.dp2px(mImageView.getContext(), 38))
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
                            .into(mImageView);
                    sharedWithView.addView(mImageView);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

try `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` inside the `LinearLayout`

Comment: thanks @medhdj: applying ` android:layout_width="wrap_content" ` to both `HorizontalScrollView` and `LinearLayout` worked for me :)